# Puppeteer generated PDF Copy/Paste text produce weird characters

Tags: javascript, pdf, puppeteer

I'm using the latest version of puppeteer to generate the attached PDF.  When I open it in Adobe Acrobat and try to copy and paste the text, it turns

> This is a test string.

into

> Țħįș įș ǻ țěșț șțřįňģ.

Here is my code for generating PDF.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
const fileName = argv.fileName || "page";
const timeout = 90;

(async () => {
  var pageUrl = "my-url-here"
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  function onTimeout() {
    console.log("Timed out waiting for data after " + timeout + " seconds.");
    process.exit();
  }
  
  console.log("Opening " + pageUrl);
  await page.goto(pageUrl, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  console.log("Waiting for page to load...");
  
  console.log("Waiting for data to load...");
  await page.waitForSelector('#print-report-loaded', {timeout:timeout*1000}).catch(onTimeout);
  
  var fileFullName = fileName + ".pdf";
  console.log("Saving PDF as " + fileFullName);
  await page.pdf({path: fileFullName});
  console.log("PDF saved successfully as " + fileFullName);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

[Here is link to the generated PDF](http://jmp.sh/v/54E5lnC7pCr4HEawUNxA)

Any idea how to fix would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrobat does not *change* the text, it merely copies the Unicode characters that are stored for these fonts. The 'characters' you see are Type 3 outlines, and they have the *form* of "regular" characters but their associated Unicode code points are indeed those of heavily accented characters.

From the perspective of both Acrobat Reader and the official PDF specifications, everything is "working as designed".

Let's take a look inside your PDF.

To  unnecessarily complicate things, one would think this only needs one font, but your tool generated *two* fonts: `F0`, which maps character codes to the following Unicode codes

```
<(01)> <( )>
<(0D)> <(.)>
<(26)> <(Ț)>
<(32)> <(ǻ)>
<(35)> <(ě)>
<(37)> <(ģ)>
<(38)> <(ħ)>
<(39)> <(į)>
<(3E)> <(ň)>
<(42)> <(ț)>
```

and `F1` which maps to

```
<(15)> <(ř)>
<(16)> <(ș)>
```

Character codes are written out as a string, one character at a time (and with a few commands in between; omitted here because not really relevant):

```
<26><38><39>{16}<01><39>{16}<01><32><01><42><35>{16}<42><01>{16}<42>{15}<39><3E><37><0D>
```

where I indicated that hex codes paired inside `<..>` are from font `F0` and `{..}` are from `F1`. Now, if you replace the character indexes one by one with the Unicode characters, you indeed get the Unicode string

```
Țħįș įș ǻ țěșț șțřįňģ.
```

The "fonts" used here are Type 3 PostScript fonts, fully embedded inside the PDF. Font #0, for example, is defined as

```
8 0 obj @ 1059      % "F0"
<<
  /Type     /Font
  /Subtype  /Type3
  /CIDToGIDMap  /Identity
  /CharProcs    
  <<
    /g0     11 0 R      % -> stream
    /g1     12 0 R      % -> stream
    /g26    14 0 R      % -> stream
    /g32    15 0 R      % -> stream
    /g35    16 0 R      % -> stream
    /g37    17 0 R      % -> stream
    /g38    18 0 R      % -> stream
    /g39    19 0 R      % -> stream
    /g3E    20 0 R      % -> stream
    /g42    21 0 R      % -> stream
    /gD     13 0 R      % -> stream
  >>
  /Encoding     
  <<
    /Type   /Encoding
    /Differences [ 0 /g0 /g1 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /gD /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0
        /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g26 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0
        /g0 /g32 /g0 /g0 /g35 /g0 /g37 /g38 /g39 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g0 /g3E /g0 /g0 /g0 /g42 ]
  >>
  /FirstChar    0
  /FontBBox     [ -1 202 598 -801 ]
  /FontDescriptor 10 0 R        % -> FontDescriptor (Font)
  /FontMatrix   [ 0.082254 0 0 -0.082254 0 0 ]
  /LastChar     66
  /ToUnicode    9 0 R       % -> stream
  /Widths   [ 500 300 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 244 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 641 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 579 0
      0 592 0 664 616 263 0 0 0 0 616 0 0 0 404 ]
>>
endobj
```

Most of this is not important, except for the *encoding array*, which tells what *character index* associates with what glyph name, and the `CharProcs` array, which associates the *names* in the encoding array with actual drawing instructions. This is the route from "font name plus character index" in displaying a string, towards "character index in encoding", which in turn uses the `ToUnicode` array to look up *actual* (reported) Unicode values for each character.

The drawing instructions for each character themselves (the references to each `/gX` stream) are a regular series of `move`, `line`, and `fill` instructions – again, nothing unusual, although other PDF engines more often include the original font, rather than only the literal drawing instructions.

But the `ToUnicode` table messes up things for copying. Instead of stating "character `16#26` maps to Unicode U+0054 'Latin Capital T'", it points to "U+021A Latin Capital T with Comma Below" – and for no apparent reason! It is most certainly not a *random* translation, but I cannot find *any* reasonable explanation for why one would deliberately encode plain text as such ... unless there is someone out there grinning contently and thinking, "yes, this *is* what I had in mind" – in which case it would be a *deliberate obfuscation*.

The Puppeteer code at Github does not appear to handle PDFs itself, so it must be handled by Chromium, which internally uses the Skia PDF engine (reportedly but substantiated by the PDF binary header, which reads "D3 EB E9 E1" – "Skia", when the highest bit is zeroed out). It has been reported as a bug [as early as 2012](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108937) but there are reports from 2017, which seems to indicate it is not a pressing issue to fix at their side.

Comment: It's fun looking into PDFs like that... ;)

Comment: @mkl: it is – and this output comes from a tool I wrote by myself from scratch `:D` It works extremely well to inspect most PDFs ... but alas not for *all*.

Comment: Is the tool publicly available?

Comment: @mkl: no. It's one *huge* C source, pretty much unmaintainable, and I am forever tinkering with it, trying to make it work with more PDFs.

Comment: Well, should you ever consider publishing it (and be it as an ongoing develop branch in a daily updated github repo), I'd be interested. ;)